# calculate $ \pi_{1}\left(T_{2}\#T_{2}\right) $

Tags: algebraic-topology

How can I calculate $\pi_{1}\left(T_{2}\#T_{2}\right)$ ?

I know that this is a covering space of a tori which means that this group is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$.

Thanks!

Comment: seifert-van kampen

Comment: That's a covering space of the torus?

Comment: Can you show how you use the Van-Kampen theorem and the answer?

Comment: Why don't you try to work it and show us how you are approaching the problem and ask a SPECIFIC question when you get stuck. There are lots of examples done in various textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the connected sum as the union of the tori with disk removed; the intersection of these open sets is a (thickened) circle. The fundamental group of a torus with a disk removed is $\mathbb{Z}\star\mathbb{Z}$ (look at the usual CW complex giving the torus, remove a disk, and you have a wedge of circles). Write $h_1, v_1$ for the generators of this free group on two letters coming from the first torus, and $h_2, v_2$ for the same coming from the second torus.

Then the circle included on the intersection is identified with $h_1v_1h_1^{-1}v_1^{-1}$ on the first torus and $h_2v_2h_2^{-2}v_2^{-2}$ on the second (draw the same picture of a standard CW complex with a disk removed). Hence by Van Kampen the fundamental group of the connected sum is 
$$
\langle h_1, v_1, h_2, v_2 | h_1v_1h_1^{-1}v_1^{-1} = h_2v_2h_2^{-2}v_2^{-2}\rangle.
$$

Comment: by the way, the group in question is not abelian, in particular not a subgroup of the fundamental group of the torus, which gives an algebraic proof that this connected sum doesn't cover the torus